# I want to fill data with javascript in selenium vba

Tags: vba, selenium, web-scraping

I have a web form of pre populated data which i have to fill. I want to do this with javascript. I am not sure to write the code .

```
Public Sub ABC()
    Dim document As HTMLDocument
    Dim bot As New WebDriver
    Dim  cSCRIPT,m
    m=58
    bot.Start "chrome", ""
    bot.Get "https://XYZ"
  cSCRIPT = "document.getElementByXPath("//td[contains(text(),'XXXX')]/following-sibling::td[5]").value='" & m & "'"
 bot.ExecuteScript cSCRIPT
```

But my code do not work. How can I code in selenium VBA with the help of XPath to fill data in Web table.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I recognised you might genuinely want JavaScript solution which is why i gave a JavaScript based answer. No feelings hurt :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test this in VBA but have translated from python which worked. I use `evaluate` to handle the xpath matching.

The function `Document.evaluate()` has the following definition:

```
var xpathResult = document.evaluate(
  xpathExpression,
  contextNode,
  namespaceResolver,
  resultType,
  result
);
```

The first argument is the xpath expression. Then `contextNode` is basically the node to apply the xpath to i.e. `document` in this case. `namespaceResolver` is `null` as no namespace prefixes are used (it's an html document). I specify `resultType` as `XPathResult.ANY_TYPE` so as to get the natural type from the expression. For `result` argument I pass `null` so as to create a new `XPathResult`.

The return type is `object`. I use `iterateNext` to get to the `input` element and then assign the visual value with `input.value = "abc";` and the actual with `input.setAttribute('value', 'xyz');`.

I am using a testable example but you would amend as per your html which means your xpath would be

```
//td[contains(text(),'XXXX')]/following-sibling::td[5]/input
```

---

**VBA:**

```
Dim s As String
s = "var td = document.evaluate(""//tr[contains(td/text(), 'Angelica Ramos')]/td[2]/input"", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);" & _
    "var input = td.iterateNext();" & _
    "input.value = 'abc';" & _
    "input.setAttribute('value', 'xyz');"

bot.Get 'https://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html'
bot.ExecuteScript s
```

---

**Python original:**

```
bot.get('https://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html')

s = '''var td = document.evaluate("//tr[contains(td/text(), 'Angelica Ramos')]/td[2]/input", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);     
       var input = td.iterateNext();
       input.value = 'abc';
       input.setAttribute('value', 'xyz');
'''
bot.execute_script(s)
```

---

---

References:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate#Result_types
3. https://javascript.info/object
4. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XPathResult/singleNodeValue
5. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XPathResult/iterateNext

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to debug the XPath without seeing the table and underlying HTML for the webpage, but typically if a table is tough to access, I just use a macro tool like AppRobotic to leverage screen X,Y coordinates of the table to click into it and fill in the necessary info, sometimes navigating using keyboard strokes while in the table works well also:

```
Set Waiter = CreateObject("Selenium.Waiter")
Set Assert = CreateObject("Selenium.Assert")
Set bot = CreateObject("Selenium.FirefoxDriver")
Set x = CreateObject("AppRobotic.API")
Sub ABC
    ' Open webpage
    bot.Get "https://www.google.com"
    ' Wait a couple of seconds
    x.Wait(2000)
    ' Type in the Search box
    bot.FindElementByName("q").SendKeys "test"
    bot.Keys.Return
    ' Or use coordinates if an element is difficult to find
    ' Use UI Item Explorer to get X,Y coordinates of Search box and move cursor
    x.MoveCursor(438, 435)
    ' click inside Search box
    x.MouseLeftClick
    x.Type("test")
    x.Type("{ENTER}")
    While Waiter.Not(Instr(bot.Title, "test")): Wend
    x.MessageBox("Click OK to quit the browser"):
    bot.Quit
End Sub
```