# How to fix 'for each' iteration with getELementsbyTagName?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, msxml

I'm using MSXML and WinHTTP within VBA/Excel. I'm attempting to extract 'innertext' from all

tag elements within a  element.

How can the sub iterate through all

tags within a specific class and populate a worksheet?

Thanks in advance.

I'm trying adapt this strategy [0] to this website [1]

[0] https://codingislove.com/parse-html-in-excel-vba/
[1] https://www.fool.com/earnings/call-transcripts/2019/07/17/netflix-inc-nflx-q2-2019-earnings-call-transcript.aspx

```
Sub tryKeywordsearch()

Dim http As Object, html As New HTMLDocument
Dim paras As Object, titleElem As Object, detailsElem As Object, para As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim i As Integer
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", "https://www.fool.com/earnings/call-transcripts/2019/07/17/netflix-inc-nflx-q2-2019-earnings-call-transcript.aspx", False
http.Send
html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText

Set paras = html.getElementsByClassName("article-content")

i = 1

For Each para In paras
    Set para = para.getElementsByTagName("p")(i)
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = para.innerText
    i = i + 1
Next
End sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is in fact only one element with that class name, `article-content`, so you are doing an outer loop of one and thus get no further than `i = 1`. Additionally, during your first loop you are changing the variable you are looping over which will most likely lead to an error.

```
For Each para In paras
    Set para = para.getElementsByTagName("p")(i)
```

In the above, `para` is your loop variable.

Also, the collection returned by `para.getElementsByTagName("p")` will start at `0`.

How your code would work is if you indexed into initial collection returned by `getElementsByClassName` and then chain on `getElementsByTagName`, and use that as your collection to `For Each` over (leaving index starting at 1 as you can then use it to write out to the correct row; you can use your loop variable `para` to get the current node `innerText`):

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TryKeywordSearch()
    Dim http As Object, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim paras As Object, para As Object, i As Long

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", "https://www.fool.com/earnings/call-transcripts/2019/07/17/netflix-inc-nflx-q2-2019-earnings-call-transcript.aspx", False
    http.send
    html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
    Set paras = html.getElementsByClassName("article-content")(0).getElementsByTagName("p")
    i = 1
    For Each para In paras
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = para.innerText
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Instead, you can use a faster, and more readable IMO, [css selector combination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) to get all `p` tags within a parent with class `article-content`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetParagraphs()
    Dim http As Object, html As HTMLDocument, paragraphs As Object, i As Long
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.fool.com/earnings/call-transcripts/2019/07/17/netflix-inc-nflx-q2-2019-earnings-call-transcript.aspx", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Set paragraphs = html.querySelectorAll(".article-content p")
    For i = 0 To paragraphs.Length - 1
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 1) = paragraphs.item(i).innerText
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I used to frequent this blog [codingislove](https://codingislove.com/parse-html-in-excel-vba/) upon a time. Btw, do you have any idea whether there is any route through which I can use xpath within vba?

Comment: @sim sort of... either use Microsoft XML library and parse with that or use execScript and use javascript - though you can't return objects you can store values in existing nodes via javascript and then read back with html parser.

Comment: I think I ran into problems when trying to create new nodes - will need to look at that again.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57070070/6241235

Comment: Where should I report for this shortcoming? Bill gates?

Comment: lol.... it is weird isn't it but then it's an old set of products. Writing python is suddenly like being shown the entire house when you have been living in a room.

Comment: @QHarr - Impressive. Thank you. Your suggestion was elegant and, best of all, it worked!